# Can I change the error message given by the compiler in scala?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I have key and body case classes. Let's say the keys extend the `Key` trait and bodies extend the `Body` trait. For every key, there is exactly one given body type. Below, I have tried to program this in a way that the compiler can check this for me and it even seems to work!

```
trait Key [T <: Body]
trait Body

case class Body1 () extends Body
case class Body2 () extends Body

case class Key1 () extends Key[Body1]
case class Key2 () extends Key[Body2]

object Tester {
  def func[T <: Body](key: Key[T], body: T) = {
    println("Key: "+ key, "Body: "+body)
  }

  val k1 = Key1()
  val b1 = Body1()
  val b2 = Body2()
  func(k1, b1)  // good match
  func(k1, b2)  // wrong match
}
```

As I want, the last line above gives a compile-time error (see below). But can I make it a bit more readable so that users of my library will understand what's happening? Especially, the last "hint" is misleading in my case.

```
Error:(18, 9) type mismatch;
 found   : A$A60.this.Key1
 required: A$A60.this.Key[Product with Serializable with A$A60.this.Body]
Note: A$A60.this.Body1 <: Product with Serializable with A$A60.this.Body (and A$A60.this.Key1 <: A$A60.this.Key[A$A60.this.Body1]), but trait Key is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
  func(k1, b2)
       ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `implicitNotFound` can change compile msg

```
import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound

trait Key[T <: Body]    
trait Body

case class Body1() extends Body    
case class Body2() extends Body

case class Key1() extends Key[Body1]    
case class Key2() extends Key[Body2]

@implicitNotFound("Expected ${From}, but found ${To}.")
class CompileMsg[From, To]

object CompileMsg {
  implicit def implValue[T] = new CompileMsg[T, T]
}

object Tester {
  def func[KeyBody <: Body, BodyBody <: Body]
  (key: Key[KeyBody], body: BodyBody)
  (implicit msg: CompileMsg[KeyBody, BodyBody]) = {
    println("Key: " + key, "Body: " + body)
  }

  val k1: Key1  = Key1()
  val b1        = Body1()
  val b2: Body2 = Body2()
  func(k1, b1) // good match
  func(k1, b2) // wrong match
}
```

now , gives you the following error msg:

```
Error:(35, 8) keyBody is A$A57.this.Body1 != A$A57.this.Body2
func(k1, b2) // wrong match
^
```

Comment: Nice solution! I am thinking if this can be simplified, but I guess not. Can we get rid of the `A$A57.this`?

Comment: if only use `implicitNotFound `,i also not way  get rid it , but if  use macro  we can ;  but macro is difficult to learn : http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/usecases.html